# Render asp.TextBox for html5 input type="date"

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms, textbox

I don't know if it has been asked before, couldn't find it either.

Is it possible to control the type of the input text that is rendered by an asp:TextBox? I would like to change it to `<input type="date">`

any suggestions or comments are welcome, thanks

Answer (score 31):

There is an update for .NET framework 4 which allows you to specify the type attribute

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871.

See `feature 3` way down the page

> Feature 3
>
> New syntax lets you define a
>   TextBox control that is HTML5
>   compatible. For example, the following
>   code defines a TextBox control that is
>   HTML5 compatible:
>
> ```
> <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="some-HTML5-type" />
> ```

Comment: That's good news but not all of us can upgrade our legacy apps to .NET 4.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind subclassing, you can do this by overidding AddAttributesToRender

```
public class DateTextbox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
{
    protected override void AddAttributesToRender(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute("type", "date");
        base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did it... hope it helps...

Add a new item to your project of the type "JScript File", then paste this code in:

```
var setNewType;
if (!setNewType) {
setNewType = window.onload = function() {
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].getAttribute('xtype')) {
            a[i].setAttribute('type', a[i].getAttribute('xtype'));
            a[i].removeAttribute('xtype');
        };
    }
}
```

Now add this line into your aspx page after the **body** tag (change the file name to whatever you called it above!):
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="setNewType.js"></script>`

Finally, add something like the following to your code behind PageLoad ( I used VB here):

```
aspTxtBxId.Attributes("xtype") = "tel" ' or whatever you want it to be
```

The important part above is the *Attributes.("xtype")*, as it places the attribute XTYPE in the rendered html for the "textbox", which the javascript then finds and uses to replace the original "type" attribute.

Good Luck!
FJF

Comment: I remember that previous versions of IE (not sure about IE9) did not allow changing input types through javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I was having the same issue in a Web Forms application. You need to use TextMode

While the documentation states that

> Use the TextMode property to specify how a TextBox control is displayed. Three common options are single-line, multiline, or password text box.

You can also use html5, date, time, number, etc built in Visual Studio 2012/2013.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is the RIGHT answer. I was sick of the warning messages, and I hate disabling warnings. I don't know why I didn't think of textmode - of course MS can't use the native property name.

Answer (score 1):

I went the route of building my own set of [html5 inputs](http://www.html5asp.com) by building custom controls.  I get the custom keyboards on iPad and iPhone plus the postback coding of true asp.net controls.  It worked for my inhouse project, so I decided to license the whole suite to save other people the time and trouble of doing it from scratch.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no easy way to override the type attribute in standart asp:TextBox. 
You can simly use an input element

Here is an example

```
<input type="date" id="Input1" runat="server" />
```

Let me know if it helps...

Comment: Designer doesn't permit that type !

Comment: Yes, you are right. Another way is to inherit the TextBox and to override AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer) method.
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "date");